# Power Query transpose and pivot list

Tags: excel

I have the following list in Excel Powerquery:

[image]

I would like to transform this list within the Power Query editor to make the following list:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a source table called Table1, you could use this (in the advanced editor):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Buffered = Table.Buffer(Source),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Buffered, {"value"}, {{"AllRows", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Record", 1, 1), type table}}),
    #"Expanded AllRows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "AllRows", {"value2", "Record"}, {"value2", "Record"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded AllRows", List.Distinct(#"Expanded AllRows"[value]), "value", "value2"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Record"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```